# Strange Visual Studio 2008 Crash when editing CSS or in Designer - help!

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

So visual studio 2008 SP1 has started crashing on me when working on web applications, and nothing I do seems to work.

Things I've done:
- Reinstalled
- Uninstalled the web authoring component and reinstalled - this seems to fix the problem for about an hour
- Cleared temp files
- Run VS in safe mode

Yet, when in design view, or editing a CSS file, VS will vanish, and the only message I get in the systems logs is:
.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.4927 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (66346BA8) (80131506)

Im running VS 2008 with MVC installed (although what I'm working on is not MVC) on Windows 7 64bit with every update out there installed.

Any help would be really appreciated as this thing is driving me nuts!

Thanks

Comment: Until a fix is found, why not use a VM to get a stable VS 2k8 under XP as it maybe a Win7 based issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps, but you can try sending the problem report to Microsoft. (Send report when presented with the option, after the crash).

They tend to be helpful.

Comment: I probably will get in contact with them, but alas, im not getting any 'send info to MS' option after the crash. VS is just vanishing!
Thanks for the tip though - im just getting stressed as I have an deadline in a few hours!